# Where to find examples for easy task manager

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I am a junior java developer.
I have to make a project that requires me to have 2 kind of users, managers and normal ones.
The manager may add new duties to the normal users, register new users in the system, view everything etc.
The normal users can only view information related with them.
I am able to do this by my own but I am required to use MVC architecture and I am a little confused.
Please if anyone know where can I find any similar project it will help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best you can do is use Struts framework to implement your application (http://struts.apache.org/). Simple, universally used, realizes MVC pattern in a very easy and understandable way, supports user handling and so on.
If, on the other hand, you are not allowed to use frameworks...

Well you should struct your application with jsp, servlets and POJOs in order to implement MVC custom. JSPs just handle page layout, Servlets manage navigation and general application control and POJOs (Plain Old Java Objects) realize your business logic, in order to keep in separated layers the "look", the navigation issues and the business.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this helped me to clarify smth :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a lot of context but judging by your tags (which include JSP and Servlet) then consider taking a look at the Web application technology stack project [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home). It will generate a Web Application project for you using Maven, the project builds on top of the state-of-the-art in Web Development. The generated project has exactly the functionality you are [vaguely] describing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. as I said I am a little confused by myself that is why I am in need for some examples. AppFuse is nice but not what I am asking. I need some examples of any Simple Task Manager, where the admins have their roles and users or employees have their own. I must use JSP, Servlets and MVC architecture for this.